# Control.Location.X in dynamic controls.?

Tags: c#, winforms

So,

i tried to add a Label control to Forms Controls collection.

`this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "dynamic label", Location.X = 100 , Location.Y=100});`

but, when i do this, the compiler throws an error saying that the Location property here is the Form.Location property and it cannot be modified.

but,

when i do,

`this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Name = "dynamicLabel", Text = "dynamic label text", Location=new Point(100,100)});`

there is no error, and the Location property is taken as the property of Label control.

my question is, why is there this difference when i'm basically doing the same thing.?

Comment: You can not set properties of properties in an object initializer.  You can only set the direct properties of the object you are initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set properties of properties in an object initializer. You can only set the direct properties of the object you are initializing.